# How to fix retryWrites in Mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using mlab.com mongoDB and i can query into it but i can't insert into it

#### That's my class

```
public class Main
{
    private MongoUrl _url;
    private MongoClient _client;

    public Main(MongoUrl url)
    {
        url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://username:password@ds062807.mlab.com:62807/robobalancedb");
        _url = url;
        _client = new MongoClient(_url);
    }

    public async Task Login([Option]string username, [Option]string password)
    {

        var db = _client.GetDatabase("robobalancedb");

        var col = db.GetCollection<User>("users"); 

        var user = await (await col.FindAsync(x => x.Name == username && x.Password == password)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    }

    public async Task Supply([Option(ShortName="u")] string username, [Option(ShortName="a")]double amount, [Option(ShortName="d")]string description)
    {

        var db = _client.GetDatabase("robobalancedb");
        var col = db.GetCollection<OwnerSupply>("ownersupplies");

        var supply = new OwnerSupply(){
            Amount = amount,
            Description = description
        };

        await col.InsertOneAsync(supply);
    }
}
```

#### Exception

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jkSO.jpg

after searching I have tried to add ?retryWrites=true to my connection string
`mongodb://username:password@ds062807.mlab.com:62807/?retryWrites=true/robobalancedb`

I got the Exception

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: 'retryWrites has an invalid boolean value of false/robobalancedb.'

and have tried to set RetryWrites in _client field by

```
_client.Settings.RetryWrites = false;
```

got Exception 
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'MongoClientSettings is frozen.'`

Comment: Did you try `mongodb://username:password@ds062807.mlab.com:62807/robobalancedb?replyWrites=false` ?

Comment: Yep I have tried it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved it by putting `retryWrites=false` at the end of connection string

`mongodb://username:password@ds062807.mlab.com:62807/robobalancedb?retryWrites=false`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it without touching the connexionstring throught code :

```
var url = new MongoUrl(Configuration.GetValue<string>("MongoConnection"));
var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(url);
mongoClientSettings.RetryWrites = false;
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings));
```